# Creating new variable based on two other columns containing categories with tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to manipulate data and want to create new variable based on two columns both with categorical levels. I have tried to achieve this with tidyverse, in 3 ways ( need to stick with this library).

This is what I have tried.

```
data_indices <- df_subs %>%
   mutate(ifelse(sex == "Female" & patient.class == "Not_Admitted", "female_not_admitted",
          ifelse(sex == "Female" & patient.class == "ORDINARY ADMISSION", "female_admitted",
          ifelse(sex == "Male" & patient.class == "Not_Admitted", "male_not_admitted",
          ifelse(sex == "Male" & patient.class == "ORDINARY ADMISSION",  "male_admitted")))))
```

Yet, I got an error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: argument "no" is missing, with no default.
```

Secondly, I have also tried unite function in tidyverse yet did not succeed.

And finally, thirdly, I have searched and found the group indices, in the same library. This is what I have do but failed miserably. :)

```
data_indices <- ds_sum_age_sex %>%
  bind_cols(Group_indic = group_indices("patient.class", "sex"))
```

With an error:

```
 Error in UseMethod("group_indices_") : 
 no applicable method for 'group_indices_' applied to an object of class 
 "character"
```

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit hard to understand what you need the functions to do. But here is a guess :)

```
df_subs <- data.frame(sex = c("Male", 
                              "Female", 
                              "Female"),
                      patient.class = c("Not_Admitted", 
                                        "ORDINARY ADMISSION", 
                                        "ORDINARY ADMISSION"))

# Question 1
df_subs %>% 
  mutate(sex_patient_class = case_when(
    sex == "Female" & patient.class == "Not_Admitted"          ~ "female_not_admitted",
    sex == "Female" & patient.class == "ORDINARY ADMISSION"    ~ "female_admitted",
    sex == "Male"   & patient.class == "Not_Admitted"          ~ "male_not_admitted",
    sex == "Male"   & patient.class == "ORDINARY ADMISSION"    ~ "male_admitted"
  ))

# Question 2
df_subs %>% 
  unite(sex_patient_class, sex, patient.class, sep = "_")

# Question 3
df_subs %>% 
  mutate(group_indices = group_indices(., patient.class, sex))
```

Comment: @ Charlicito - I need to get one column from those two, gender and patient.class - and tried all three examples I have given. Is that clearer now?

Comment: @ Charlicito - I need to get one column from those two, gender and patient.class - and tried all three examples I have given. Is that clearer now? Tried them all worked nicely. Thanks!