# Create a column with multiple categories based on string patterns in Tidyverse

Tags: r, string, if-statement, tidyverse

[I checked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372082/create-column-based-on-presence-of-string-pattern-and-ifelse), but not sure how to make it for multiple categories (not just two). [This is conceptually similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862785/creating-new-variable-based-on-two-other-columns-containing-categories-with-tidy), but not sure it is a good option for strings.

I have a dataframe

```
Gender          Frequency 
female            49719         
male              14835         
NA                712           
female, male      518
```

Moreover, there are much more options like `female, female, female` or `male, male, female`. I have dozens of combinations.

I would like to have a new column where I will have only four categories - `male`, `female`, `both`, `NA`. For instance, if one fender `female` is repeated multiple times, classify it as `female`. If it is a combination of different genders (any length) - call it `both`.

Desired output:

```
Gender          Frequency      Category
female            49719          female 
male              14835          male
NA                712            NA
female, male      518            both
male, male, male  100            male
male, male, female 100           both
```

I would appreciate a `tidyverse` solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(Gender, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(Category = if(n_distinct(Gender) > 1) 'both' else unique(Gender), 
            Gender = toString(Gender), 
            Frequency = first(Frequency)) %>%
  select(Gender, Frequency, Category)

#  Gender             Frequency Category
#  <chr>                  <int> <chr>   
#1 female                 49719 female  
#2 male                   14835 male    
#3 NA                       712 NA      
#4 female, male             518 both    
#5 male, male, male         100 male    
#6 male, male, female       100 both
```

Or

```
df %>%
  mutate(Category = map_chr(str_split(Gender, ',\\s*'), 
                          ~if(n_distinct(.) > 1) 'both' else unique(.)))
```

which can be translated in base R -

```
df$Category <- sapply(strsplit(df$Gender, ',\\s*'), function(x) 
                   if(length(unique(x)) > 1) 'both' else unique(x))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a perfect solution. It looks like I gave the wrong dataframe, but I will try to apply it to a different dataframe too! Thanks!